# Aligning facebook login button in nav bar of bootstrap web page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web design and I need help in aligning facebook login button in the nav bar of my webpage. Right now the button wraps around to the next line in the nav bar and when I put the button within <\li> tag it still doesn't align. Attaching the html code below for reference. 
I use bootstrap css   and below is the updated code snippet

```
               <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                  <li> <a href="Index.php">Home</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Rules</a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Gallery</a> </li>
                  <li class="new">
                      <div class="fb-login-button" 
                            data-max-rows="1" 
                            data-size="medium" 
                            data-show-faces="false" 
                            data-scope="public_profile,email" 
                            vertical-align="middle" 
                            data-auto-logout-link="true" 
                            onlogin="checkLoginState()">
                        </div>
                    </li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: Also provide us your CSS which is controlling this section of the website, and also only provide the code which needs updating, not everything. Have you got a live URL so we can see what's happening, or maybe a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your files in to my local environment and did some modifications as needed.

As of now without seeing your CSS codes I can give solution which is as follows:

Make your HTML code for button inside the ul you defined already.

Change your HTML code as follows:

```
<li class="new"><button class="facebook-login"> fb login</button><li>
```

Then provide CSS for the same as follows:

```
.new {
float: left;
margin-top: 2%;}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: hi, your solution works. Thanks,but in my actual code I use fb login using bootstrap css and it doesnt work there

Comment: @RajkumarKaliyaperumal Ok, Then you can !important to your css

.new {
float: left !important;
margin-top: 2% !important;}

Just change the class name if needed.